# in jsp,how to show progressbar while uploading the file

Tags: jsp

i need to show the progress bar in same page when user select the file and clicks upload button in the same page.In jsp,how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) offers a very nice way to do file uploads.  It offers

> "multiple file selection, drag&drop support, progress bars and preview
>   images"

You can use it alongside your server-side technology (JSP in your case).